# Google API Client for .Net: Implement retry when a request fails

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

How can I implement retries in case a request that is part of a batch request fails when interacting with google's API. In their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/limits), they suggest adding "Exponential Backoff" algorithm. I'm using the following [code](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/batch) snippet in their documentation:

```
UserCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
        "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Calendar.Sample.Store"));
}

// Create the service.
var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "Google Calendar API Sample",
    });

// Create a batch request.
var request = new BatchRequest(service);
request.Queue<CalendarList>(service.CalendarList.List(),
     (content, error, i, message) =>
     {
         // Put your callback code here.
     });
request.Queue<Event>(service.Events.Insert(
     new Event
     {
         Summary = "Learn how to execute a batch request",
         Start = new EventDateTime() { DateTime = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0) },
         End = new EventDateTime() { DateTime = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0) }
     }, "YOUR_CALENDAR_ID_HERE"),
     (content, error, i, message) =>
     {
         // Put your callback code here.
     });
// You can add more Queue calls here.

// Execute the batch request, which includes the 2 requests above.
await request.ExecuteAsync();
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting exactly that makes you think it has failed.  The google .net client library already implements Exponential Backoff for you.

Comment: @DaImTo I'm getting a "403 quotaExceeded" error when I try multiple request in batch(I'm still under the limit since I'm only doing a max of 30 request at the time).

Comment: @DalmTo according to their documentation, Exponetial Backoff is enabled by default to handle 503 responses, but in my case I'd need to handle a 403. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/reference/1.9.1/namespaceGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Http#a0bcc672afd8ddb40cf5fd149aa40f3e2

Comment: Hmm i thought we where handeling all of the Backoffs now.  I dont think that documentation has been updated in years. but i will check.   I will check with the team in the mean time you might like this https://www.daimto.com/google-apis-flood-buster/  this is the best i have ever come up with.

Comment: Thanks for sharing @DaImTo. Like you said on the post, the implementation works on reducing the amount of errors we get from Google's API, but it doesn't guarantee that all of my request are going to make it through. It solves part of the issue, but not the retry.

Comment: Google documentation mentions " retry-able error code" I have not been able to find any documentation on this. Do you know anything about it @DaImTo

Comment: There will be no way to ensure that every request goes through.    What if Google service is down you can't just keep trying

Comment: You're correct, but as google suggest, I'd like to retry a few times before I consider it a failure. @DaImTo

Comment: The code I gave you is what I use

Comment: I've posted the approach I took to solve a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53584429/google-api-client-for-net-how-to-implement-exponential-backoff/53619677#53619677

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple helper class to make it easy to implement exponential backoff for a lot of the situations that Google talks about on their API error page: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors

**How to Use:**

- Edit the class below to include your client secret and application name as you set up on https://console.developers.google.com
- In the startup of your application (or when you ask the user to authorize), call `GCalAPIHelper.Instance.Auth();`
- Anywhere you would call the Google Calendar API (eg Get, Insert, Delete, etc), instead use this class by doing: `GCalAPIHelper.Instance.CreateEvent(event, calendarId);` (you may need to expand this class to other API endpoints as your needs require)

```cs
using Google;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using static Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.CalendarListResource.ListRequest;

/*======================================================================================
 * This file is to implement Google Calendar .NET API endpoints WITH exponential backoff.
 * 
 * How to use:
 *    - Install the Google Calendar .NET API (nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3)
 *    - Edit the class below to include your client secret and application name as you 
 *      set up on https://console.developers.google.com
 *    - In the startup of your application (or when you ask the user to authorize), call
 *      GCalAPIHelper.Instance.Auth();
 *    - Anywhere you would call the Google Calendar API (eg Get, Insert, Delete, etc),
 *      instead use this class by doing: 
 *      GCalAPIHelper.Instance.CreateEvent(event, calendarId); (you may need to expand
 *      this class to other API endpoints as your needs require) 
 *======================================================================================
 */

namespace APIHelper
{
    public class GCalAPIHelper
    {
        #region Singleton
        private static GCalAPIHelper instance;

        public static GCalAPIHelper Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                    instance = new GCalAPIHelper();

                return instance;
            }
        }
        #endregion Singleton

        #region Private Properties
        private CalendarService service { get; set; }
        private string[] scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar };
        private const string CLIENTSECRETSTRING = "YOUR_SECRET"; //Paste in your JSON client secret here. Don't forget to escape special characters!
        private const string APPNAME = "YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"; //Paste in your Application name here
        #endregion Private Properties

        #region Constructor and Initializations
        public GCalAPIHelper()
        {

        }

        public void Auth(string credentialsPath)
        {
            if (service != null)
                return;

            UserCredential credential;
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(CLIENTSECRETSTRING);

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
            {
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    scopes,
                    Environment.UserName,
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credentialsPath, true)).Result;
            }

            service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = APPNAME
            });
        }
        #endregion Constructor and Initializations

        #region Private Methods
        private TResponse DoActionWithExponentialBackoff<TResponse>(CalendarBaseServiceRequest<TResponse> request)
        {
            return DoActionWithExponentialBackoff(request, new HttpStatusCode[0]);
        }

        private TResponse DoActionWithExponentialBackoff<TResponse>(CalendarBaseServiceRequest<TResponse> request, HttpStatusCode[] otherBackoffCodes)
        {
            int delay = 100;
            while (delay < 1000) //If the delay gets above 1 second, give up
            {
                try
                {
                    return request.Execute();
                }
                catch (GoogleApiException ex)
                {
                    if (ex.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden || //Rate limit exceeded
                        ex.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable || //Backend error
                        ex.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound ||
                        ex.Message.Contains("That’s an error") || //Handles the Google error pages like https://i.imgur.com/lFDKFro.png
                        otherBackoffCodes.Contains(ex.HttpStatusCode))
                    {
                        Common.Log($"Request failed. Waiting {delay} ms before trying again");
                        Thread.Sleep(delay);
                        delay += 100;
                    }
                    else
                        throw;
                }
            }

            throw new Exception("Retry attempts failed");
        }
        #endregion Private Methods

        #region Public Properties
        public bool IsAuthorized
        {
            get { return service != null; }
        }
        #endregion Public Properties

        #region Public Methods
        public Event CreateEvent(Event eventToCreate, string calendarId)
        {
            EventsResource.InsertRequest eventCreateRequest = service.Events.Insert(eventToCreate, calendarId);
            return DoActionWithExponentialBackoff(eventCreateRequest);
        }

        public Event InsertEvent(Event eventToInsert, string calendarId)
        {
            EventsResource.InsertRequest eventCopyRequest = service.Events.Insert(eventToInsert, calendarId);
            return DoActionWithExponentialBackoff(eventCopyRequest);
        }

        public Event UpdateEvent(Event eventToUpdate, string calendarId, bool sendNotifications = false)
        {
            EventsResource.UpdateRequest eventUpdateRequest = service.Events.Update(eventToUpdate, calendarId, eventToUpdate.Id);
            eventUpdateRequest.SendNotifications = sendNotifications;
            return DoActionWithExponentialBackoff(eventUpdateRequest);
        }

        public Event GetEvent(Event eventToGet, string calendarId)
        {
            return GetEvent(eventToGet.Id, calendarId);
        }

        public Event GetEvent(string eventIdToGet, string calendarId)
        {
            EventsResource.GetRequest eventGetRequest = service.Events.Get(calendarId, eventIdToGet);
            return DoActionWithExponentialBackoff(eventGetRequest);
        }

        public CalendarListEntry GetCalendar(string calendarId)
        {
            CalendarListResource.GetRequest calendarGetRequest = service.CalendarList.Get(calendarId);
            return DoActionWithExponentialBackoff(calendarGetRequest);
        }

        public Events ListEvents(string calendarId, DateTime? startDate = null, DateTime? endDate = null, string q = null, int maxResults = 250)
        {
            EventsResource.ListRequest eventListRequest = service.Events.List(calendarId);
            eventListRequest.ShowDeleted = false;
            eventListRequest.SingleEvents = true;
            eventListRequest.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

            if (startDate != null)
                eventListRequest.TimeMin = startDate;

            if (endDate != null)
                eventListRequest.TimeMax = endDate;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(q))
                eventListRequest.Q = q;

            eventListRequest.MaxResults = maxResults;

            return DoActionWithExponentialBackoff(eventListRequest);
        }

        public CalendarList ListCalendars(string accessRole)
        {
            CalendarListResource.ListRequest calendarListRequest = service.CalendarList.List();
            calendarListRequest.MinAccessRole = (MinAccessRoleEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MinAccessRoleEnum), accessRole);
            return DoActionWithExponentialBackoff(calendarListRequest);
        }

        public void DeleteEvent(Event eventToDelete, string calendarId, bool sendNotifications = false)
        {
            DeleteEvent(eventToDelete.Id, calendarId, sendNotifications);
        }

        public void DeleteEvent(string eventIdToDelete, string calendarId, bool sendNotifications = false)
        {
            EventsResource.DeleteRequest eventDeleteRequest = service.Events.Delete(calendarId, eventIdToDelete);
            eventDeleteRequest.SendNotifications = sendNotifications;
            DoActionWithExponentialBackoff(eventDeleteRequest, new HttpStatusCode[] { HttpStatusCode.Gone });
        }
        #endregion Public Methods
    }
}
```

Comment: Extremely nice way to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

derekantrican has an answer that I based mine off of.  Two things, if the resource is "notFound" waiting for it won't do any good.  That's them responding to the request with the object not being found, so there's no need for back off.  I'm not sure if there are other codes where I need to handle yet, but I will be looking at it closer.  According to Google: https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/exponential-backoff all 5xx and 429 should be retried.

Also, Google wants this to be an exponential back off; not linear.  So the code below handles it in a exponential way.  They also want you to add a random amount of MS to the retry timeout.  I don't do this, but it would be easy to do.  I just don't think that it matters that much.

I also needed the requests to be async so I updated the work methods to this type. See derekantrican's examples on how to call the methods; these are just the worker methods.  Instead of returning "default" on the notFound, you could also re-throw the exception and handle it upstream, too.

```
    private async Task<TResponse> DoActionWithExponentialBackoff<TResponse>(DirectoryBaseServiceRequest<TResponse> request)
    {
        return await DoActionWithExponentialBackoff(request, new HttpStatusCode[0]);
    }

    private async Task<TResponse> DoActionWithExponentialBackoff<TResponse>(DirectoryBaseServiceRequest<TResponse> request, HttpStatusCode[] otherBackoffCodes)
    {
        int timeDelay = 100;
        int retries = 1;
        int backoff = 1;

        while (retries <= 5) 
        {
            try
            {
                return await request.ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (GoogleApiException ex)
            {
                if (ex.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                    return default;
                else if (ex.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden || //Rate limit exceeded
                    ex.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable || //Backend error
                    ex.Message.Contains("That’s an error") || //Handles the Google error pages like https://i.imgur.com/lFDKFro.png
                    otherBackoffCodes.Contains(ex.HttpStatusCode))
                {
                    //Common.Log($"Request failed. Waiting {delay} ms before trying again");
                    Thread.Sleep(timeDelay);
                    timeDelay += 100 * backoff;
                    backoff = backoff * (retries++ + 1);
                }
                else
                    throw ex;  // rethrow exception
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("Retry attempts failed");
    }
```